# Can coded information be copied?

Tags: software-engineering

Could a large quantity of coded information (let's say 10,000 GB) be copied from one storage device to another without first being decoded? If so, how long would something like that take?

Comment: You say "coded". Do you mean "encoded", or "encrypted"?

Comment: I guess encrypted. That would be the more properly secured form, correct?

Comment: You can copy all of the information of course, but it will remain encrypted even on the other device.

Comment: The answer is largely the same as in the non-encoded case. The only difference is that the plaintext might be compressible, whereas the ciphertext will be hard to compress (without breaking the encryption).

Comment: *How long will it take?* Depends on the exact hardware involved, and out of scope here. Check how long it takes to copy 1GB, and multiply by 10,000 (unless the process can be parallelized somehow).

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE - which is not chat: please update the title of your question, see [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)